# JAVA 8 Interfaces method to generate guid for entity

Tags: interface, java-8, entity

I have a question, I'm trying to create interface which is implemented by a class. The main idea is a communication for frot-end and back-end by that generated UUID, when new entity it would generate the UUID and if it is not new it would use existing.

```
public interface GuidGenerator {
   default String handleGUID(String idGuid){
        return idGuid!= null ? idGuid : UUID.randomUUID().toString();
   }    
}
```

What should i change in order to make that this interface method would generate UUID each time the entity is created ?
And which is better to use in this situation static or default method for interface ?

Comment: What’s the relationship between `GuidGenerator` and the entity? If the entities are supposed to implement that interface, there is no way to assign them a UUID this way. Interfaces are not supposed to carry state. So neither, `static` nor `default` methods, are better as both are incapable of doing that.

Comment: Yes GuidGenerator is implemented by Entity

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an abstract class?

It's like an interface that implements some methods and leaves some to the subclass to implement.

See here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: Because that class already extends an abstract class and since functional interfaces were introduced in java 8 i thought it would be good to use them